# Kafka consumer group's offset stuck for one topic

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, fs2

I have an application that uses fs2-kafka for reading business events from a kafka cluster. In that application, I have multiple fs2-kafka consumers, each subscribed to a different topic. But one of the consumers seems to be stuck, as it does not consume any events.

Checking the consumer group's offsets yielded the following results:

```
GROUP      TOPIC   PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                             HOST             CLIENT-ID
consumer   topic   0          -               5               -               consumer-consumer-1-99c1c19a-faaf-40e6-a3dc-75b7d04e96f9 /10.0.3.2       consumer-consumer-1
```

(edited this slightly cause privacy)

I have also managed to get the CURRENT-OFFSET to be 1 (though, it seems like no actual consuming happened because none of my logs were triggered), but regardless - the group does not seem to want to move its offset.

The topic has just one partition and there's only one consumer/consumer group reading from that topic. There is no reason I can see for kafka to hold consumers from consuming. If it matters - that topic, as well as any other topic in this cluster, is created automatically, using kafka's "AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS". (this is a dev environment, it's simply more convinient than creating topics by hand)

The strangest thing is this - the same code, working on a different topic, *works*. Also, as it is always the case with these things, on my laptop the issue does not reproduce. There's barely any differences between my local kafka and the kafka in our dev cluster.

Originally, I had just one consumer group for the entire application. I have now tried multiple consumer groups per consumer and even sharing a consumer for reading from multiple topics. The only topic that's stuck is this one, every other topic works.

I have also tried:

- Restarting kafka and the app, updating kafka to a newer version
- Manually resetting the consumer group's offsets
- Deleting the topic

Apart from deleting all the data of kafka, I believe I have tried everything on my and kafka's side.

Comment: Have you tried using a different library?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Which one would you suggest?

Comment: Well, vanilla `kafka-clients` for a start?